# I want to display marker in the leaflet map by giving lat long values as input in search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, leaflet

I want to display marker in the leaflet map by giving lat-long values as input in a search box . I am new leaflet and javascript. I just want a simple search box where I can input the lat-long values and i get the result as a marker on map.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="input">
  <input type="text" value="19.04469, 72.9258">
  <button>Add marker</button>
</div>
```

Js:

```
     $("button").click(function() {
      var array = JSON.parse("[" + $("input").val() + "]");
      var marker = L.marker([array[0], array[1]], {
        draggable: true,
        title: "Resource location",
        alt: "Resource Location",
        riseOnHover: true
      }).addTo(map)
    });
```

Here is an quick example i put together:

http://jsfiddle.net/LnzN2/546/

If you read the docs, you should be good to make whatever you'd like.